# xquery indexof function behavior

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transform, xquery

I have a xquery that checks if a string is present in a sequence using indexof function.

`declare variable $depofilters external;
let $filters:=fn:tokenize($depofilters,',')
fn:trace((index-of($filters,'EURO') > 0))` , this returns 1 if the external variable is set to the seqeuence `('EURO','USD')`

but when I do the following,

`fn:trace((index-of($filters,$currency) > 0))` it always prints an empty value
I have verified that $currency has the correct data by doing a trace on it
and got the following output,
`xs:string:  EURO`

Can someone let me know what's going wrong?

Comment: Did you also check that `$filters` contains the correct strings? Your first code example contains multiple syntax errors, namely a missing `return` and inconsistent spelling of the `$depotFilters` variable. Does your actual code even parse?

Comment: @LeoWörteler Thanks for the reply, sorry it was a typo and I have not put down the entire xquery here. yes, I did a $filters[last()] and it printed 'USD'

Comment: @LeoWörteler I think I found the issue, its because of trailing a leading spaces when I do the $currency, I used fn:normalize-space but it doesnt remove all the whitespaces, how do I completely remove all the whitespaces?

Comment: The [tokenize(...)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize) function takes a *regex* as its second argument. You could try tokenizing with `'\s*,\s*' on the normalized string to get all whitespace. Another solution would be to just split first and then normalize whitespaces on the parts.